# How can I get a certain property inside a file created in Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<Profiles?>(
      future: readUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final user = snapshot.data;

          return user == null
              ? Center(
                  child: Text('data'),
                )
              : buildUser(user);
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ));
  }

  Future<Profiles?> readUser() async {
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profiles')
        .doc('PYq0Q1VSqQenNs3QQqE4');

    final snapshot = await docUser.get();

    if (snapshot.exists) {
      return Profiles.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
    }
  }

  Widget buildUser(Profiles profile) => ListTile(
        title: Text(profile.gender),
      );
}
```

I am successfully able to pull the 'gender' attribute inside the file identified by the id 'PYq0Q1VSqQenNs3QQqE4'.

But I want to be able to show this 'gender' feature according to the way each user saves it. For example, person X registered and chose the gender attribute as female, I want to have it write 'female' on the next page, and when person Y selects the gender attribute as 'male', I want to have it write 'male' on the next page. But I couldn't figure out how to access the gender property.